# Using API key with google javascript directions API

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to set the mode of travel when sending a request to the google javascript directions API i.e. train or bus. It requires an API key to be included when setting this option. I have an API key but what other settings do I need to change to make it work?
Do I need to add a specific website to the developer console?
and is the key included in the request itself or can it be included in the src part of the javascript with the maps URL? I've tried both options and it's not working.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=en

Comment: The key is in the html reference you make to the maps api. It is like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_key&amp;sensor=true"></script>`

Comment: Thanks toing_toing. I'm setting the origin and destination fine. It's the transit options that I'm having trouble with:  
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your_API_key&libraries=places&region=GB"></script>
 and 
//set the Veichle type i.e. bus or train if set
request.transitOptions.modes = [google.maps.TransitMode.modeOfTravel];

Comment: Just add `modes: [google.maps.TransitMode.BUS],` (for bus) to your transitOptions object literal.
Read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=en#TransitOptions

Comment: Thank you Toing_toing :) It's finally working now. I thought it would only show train journeys when mode of travel was set to train etc, but it doesn't seem to work like that. Merry Xmas and a happy new year